# How to map array of object with another array in react or javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
const arrayObj = [{
        id: 123,
        country: "IND"
        value: ""
    },
    {
        id: 153,
        country: "AUS"
        value: ""
    },
    {
        id: 183,
        country: "FRA"
        value: ""
    }
];

const value = [100, 200, 300];
```

I need to map value array into the correspondent value property in array of object

So, my array of object look like this

```
[
    {
        id: 123,
        country: "IND"
        value: 100
    },
    {
        id: 153,
        country: "AUS"
        value: 200
    },
    {
        id: 183,
        country: "FRA"
        value: 300
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can map over the `arrayObj` and use the index param to get corresponding values from `value` array.

```js
const arrayObj = [
  {
    id: 123,
    country: "IND",
    value: "",
  },
  {
    id: 153,
    country: "AUS",
    value: "",
  },
  {
    id: 183,
    country: "FRA",
    value: "",
  },
];

const value = [100, 200, 300];

const result = arrayObj.map((item, index) => ({...item, value: value[index]}));
console.log(result);

// If you don't want to create new array, you can use forEach
arrayObj.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.value = value[index];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to format very wall each object into the `arrayObj` variable, items in an array are separated by **`,`** like this `[1,2,3]` and it's the same for every `key:value` pair in an object `{item1: "itemvalue", item2: "itemvalue2"}`

```js
const arrayObj = [{
        id: 123,
        country: "IND",
        value: ""
    },
    {
        id: 153,
        country: "AUS",
        value: ""
    },
    {
        id: 183,
        country: "FRA",
        value: ""
    }
];
const value = [100, 200, 300];

const newArrayObj = arrayObj.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
    return acc.concat({...current, value: value[index]}); 
}, []);

console.log(newArrayObj);
```